# Hi there I want to know how this kind of conditional statement means? if (i == 0) lowest = highest = input;

Tags: c#

Hi there I want to know how this kind of conditional statement means?

```
if (i == 0)
{
    lowest = highest = input;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it, whats the outcome?

Comment: if `i` is equal to zero then assign the value of `input` to `highest` and to `lowest`.

Answer (score 3):

When you come across questions like this, i would recommend that you test it yourself. For instance, this can be tested in a simple console app to see what happens

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int lowest = 1;
        int input = 2;
        int highest = 3;

        Console.WriteLine("Before equality operator");
        Console.WriteLine($"lowest: {lowest}");
        Console.WriteLine($"highest: {highest}");
        Console.WriteLine($"input: {input}");


        int i = 0;
        if (i == 0) lowest = highest = input;

        Console.WriteLine("After equality operator");
        Console.WriteLine($"lowest: {lowest}");
        Console.WriteLine($"highest: {highest}");
        Console.WriteLine($"input: {input}");
    }
}
```

Output:

Before equality operator

lowest: 1

highest: 3

input: 2

After equality operator

lowest: 2

highest: 2

input: 2

Comment: And you're assuming the types are `int`...